# How to use GMRES to Matrices rather then vectors?

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods

The GMRES algorithm and its matlab implementation are supposed to solve linear equations system, such as

```
%Ax = b
A = rand(4);
b = rand(4,1);
x = gmres(A,b);
```

One can also use a function handle
    foo = @(x) A*x + conj(A)*5*x;
    y = gmres(foo,b);

What I want is to solve the following

```
B = rand(4);
H = rand(4);
foo2 = H*B + B*H;
X = gmres(foo2, B) %Will not run!
--Error using gmres (line 94)
--Right hand side must be a column vector of length 30 to match the coefficient matrix.
```

Mathematically speaking I don't see why gmres couldn't apply to this problem as well.

*Note:* What I'm really trying to solve is an implicit euler method for a PDE `dB/dt = B_xx + B_yy`, so `H` is in fact a second derivative matrix using finite difference.

Thank you
Amir

Comment: How is the 2nd example a system of linear equations? A*x = b?

Comment: I think it is equivalent to a linear system in n^2 dimensions. You take `B` to be a vector of length n^2, and then `foo2` is just multiplying from the left by a matrix of (n^2)*(n^2).

Comment: You can change this into a big system with the [Kroneker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). You have a [sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). Matlab has the functions [`sylvester`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sylvester.html) and [`kron`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) which might be useful for this prupose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood right you want to use GMRES to solve an a [sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)

```
A*X + X*A = C
```

for n-by-n matrices `A`, `X` and `C`. 
(I asked a [related question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/23137/17671) yesterday over at [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) and got [this great answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/23141/17671).)

To use GMRES you can express this matrix-matrix equation as a size `n^2` matrix-vector equation. For convenience we can use the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), implemented in MATLAB with [`kron`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
A = randn(5);
X = randi(3,[5 5]);

C = A*X + X*A;

% Use the Kronecker product to form an n^2-by-n^2 matrix
%            A*X       +        X*A
bigA = (kron(eye(5),A) + kron(A.',eye(5)));

% Quick check that we're getting the same answer
norm(bigA*X(:) - C(:))

% Use GMRES to calculate X from A and C.
vec_X_gmres = gmres(bigA,C(:));
X_gmres = reshape(vec_X_gmres,5,5);
```

Comment: Thank you. On an off-note, do you think this question is more suitable to [SciComp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Hmm, I think it's better here since it's an implementation question; but then I'm quite new to both communities, so probably not best placed to give an opinion